Is there a way to add custom app in AppOpener library for python?
So, the problem is quite simple, the App Opener library scans the pc in the first run and finds the apps by himself, but what if there are apps that App Opener didnt find? For example, I want to run the Winexp app that I downloaded myself, can i somehow add it with it's directory, so in the future i could run it too?
The code looks like this:
from AppOpener import open, close, mklist, give_appnames
open("intel graphics command center")
open("winexp")
appnames = give_appnames()

And here is the result
OPENING INTEL GRAPHICS COMMAND CENTER
WINEXP NOT FOUND... TYPE (LS) for list of applications.

I tried adding this line: mklist(name = "app_data.json")
this way I can actually see what are the apps that App Opener can run, and I tried adding custom app there with the directory, however, everytime I run the code, the app_data.json file gets updated, and the custom lines are deleted by the programm, which again gives the "*WINEXP NOT FOUND... TYPE (LS) for list of applications*" error

I don't know AppOpener but you can always read source code to see how it works and check if there is function to add program manually

here is the author of module.
If you have installed any application after the first scan of AppOpener, it doesn't automatically add that Application into the list.
It could easily be done like:
from AppOpener import open
open("update") #scan all the applications again
open("find xyz") #replace "xyz" with any app you are searching for 

Hope soo, this works!! refer to the documentation here for any additional information 
If the issue still exists, you may open an new issue in the AppOpener github repository. 
Lots of love, athrv ❤️
